# Cucumber how to run cucumber tests via mvn test command Junit 5

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, junit5, cucumber-junit

I'm developing a simple cucumber testing program in Intellij IDE, with Junit 5. 
I followed the steps, and installed the dependency as recommended in [cucumber-jvm](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine)
But When I run `mvn clean test`, the cucumber test cases are skipped

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ xxx ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ xxx ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.052 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-10-28T18:58:48-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But if I run the runner class directly through `Run Runner.java` (click run button on top-right), the tests are executed. 
This is my runner class:

```
package pirate;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME;
import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("/pirate")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pirate")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pretty, html:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.html")
public class Runner {
}
```

And this is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>xxx</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>11</source>
          <target>11</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
          <properties>
            <configurationParameters>
              cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy=long
            </configurationParameters>
          </properties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>5.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>7.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
      <version>7.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And this is my project test structure:
[image]
I want to execute all cucumber tests via `mvn test` or something similiar 
What am I missing here?

Comment: Read carefully and rename your test class to follow the conventions https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html#

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `/` in @SelectClasspathResource annotation, the correct value should be `@SelectClasspathResource("pirate")`.

Rest all looks good in your runner file.